# python regex extract multiple time in sime list

Tags: python, regex

im write this script :

```
def extractURL(data):
    links = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', data)
    scrlinks = re.findall(r'scr=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', data)
    print '+' + str(len(links))
    logfile = open('links.dat', 'a')
    for link in links:
        logfile.write('%s\n' % (link))
    for link in scrlinks:
        logfile.write('%s\n' % (link)) 
    logfile.close()
```

is possible extract multiple times whit regex in same list ? for use one time for funnction.

Comment: could you explain with an example?

Comment: can not get what you want? function looks ok.. can you explain in more details??

Comment: means you want only one variable to store result of re??

Comment: html = curl.getHTML("http://www.soldiweb.net/")
html1 = curl.getHTML("http://www.mondocompatibile.it/")
links  = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', html)
links += re.findall(r'scr=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', html1)
for link in links:
    print link

Comment: yes i want store in one variable results of re

Comment: just combine two lists.

Answer (score 0):

According to kingcope "yes i want store in one variable results of re –  kingcope"

Use list `extend` method.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l1.extend(l2)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

Or add two list

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l3 = l1+l2
>>> l3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

Use Parser to extract values of `href` an `src`

`content` is html file data.

```
>>> import lxml.html as PARSER
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(content)
>>> root.xpath("//@src")
['#333']
>>> root.xpath("//@href")
['1.com']
>>>
```

Comment: @kingcope: This is useful for you??